# AIX kernel programming help needed

Tags: kernel, aix

What is the system call table variable name in the [AIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_AIX) kernel?

I know it's called `sys_call_table[]` in the Linux kernel.

I am new to kernel programming. But I need to know in which variables in the kernel the system calls addresses are stored...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had to concern myself with the AIX kernel for a while, but it has its own way of doing things. Have you run across [Writing AIX Kernel Extensions](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-kernelext.html) in you research? I believe some of your questions might be addressed there.

Answer (score 0):

AIX use svc_table_entry as a corresponding concept of sys_call_table[]'s entry:

```
struct svc_table_entry {
    int         (*svc)();       /*  Pointer to kernel function for */
                                /*  this system call.              */
};
```

The system loader would compute numbers of syscalls and build the "system call table" on kernel heap via xmalloc dynamically. As for the name of this table, I believe it's something like "svc" or "svc64", I don't quite recall.